# C program to display parent and child process is only displaying child process instead of parent pocess

Tags: c, operating-system

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){
        int a,pid;
        printf("Do you want to create a process? Press 1 for Yes ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        if (a==1){
                fork();}
        else{printf("Fair enough");}

        printf("This should print twice");

        if (pid<0){printf(" Child process not created ");}

        else if (pid>0){printf(" This is the parent process ");}

        else{printf(" This is the child process ");}}
```

The above code displays the following output

```
>Do you want to create a process? Press 1 for Yes 1
>This should print twice This is the child process This should print twice This is the child process
```

However, I want an output, that when pressed 1, displays

```
>This should be printed twice
>This is child process
>This should be printed twice
>This is parent process
```

Could anyone point out what logical error am I committing?

Comment: I think you forgot to assign the result of `fork` to `pid`; as is, it is uninitialised. You should also think about what should happen when the user choses not to fork. (You'll probably also want to append newlines,`\n`, to your messages for tidier output or use `puts`.)

Comment: `pid = fork();` or otherwise `pid` is just random garbage. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: @Lundin
Thanks,I see.Closing topic (If I can.)

Answer (score 0):

you should check the pid you get from the fork, here is an example for child/parent code:

```
int main(){

int  a, b;

pid_t pid;

a = 3;

b = 5;

pid = fork();

if (pid == -1)

{

    printf("ERROR IN FORK MAIN\n");

}

if(pid == 0)

{

   Add( a,b) ;/*a function for child to do*/

}

else
{

    printf("Parent Done\n");

}
          return 0;}
```